# Getting source control id in JavaScript function

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have taken three textboxes over aspx page. A JavaScript function is associated with these textboxes as:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","MyFunction()");

TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","MyFunction()");

TextBox3.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","MyFunction()");
```

The `MyFunction()` is defined within a JavaScript file.

What I want is to get the control id of the textbox on which the function is associated within the JavaScript function itself. That is, the JavaScript function should look like this:

```
function MyFunction() {
   var myControl = ?;
   alert("Key press event occured in "+myControl.ID);
}
```

I need the value of `?`. What should I write there so that I could get the control id, i.e. `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, or `TextBox3` on which the event occurred?

I know that `<% =TextBox1.ClientID %>` will provide the id of `TextBox1` on client. But I think as I am attaching the onkeypress event with the textbox I should get the source control id within JavaScript function itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","MyFunction(this)");
```

JS will put the reference to the widget into `this` when the code for `onkeypress` is evaluated.

Comment: this is the easiest way to achieve a reference to the element that the event was raised on

Comment: Yep, that's the best way. Using direct reference instead of ID.

Comment: But my friends, i am not able to get the control id using 
document.getElementById(this.id);

or how should i get the id in JS function?

Comment: @IrfanRaza: Which ID are you talking about? `this` is the same thing that `getElementById()` returns, so you don't have to call it again.